# Date and time of tweets?

Tags: python, api, twitter, standards

I want to get the date and time in the standard format for a particular tweet.
This is the following code that I am using:-

```
import tweepy
import time
import datetime
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer

consumer_key = '' #your consumer key
consumer_secret = '' # your consumer secret
access_token = '' # your access token
access_secret = '' # your access secret
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


class MyListener(StreamListener):


    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            tweet=data.split('","text":"')[1].split('","source":"')[0]
            saveThis=str(time.time())+'::'+tweet
            with open('twitDB.csv', 'a') as f:
                f.write(saveThis)
                f.write('\n')
                f.close()
                return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print(str(e))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True


twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
twitter_stream.filter(track=['cars'], languages=['en'])
```

This is what I am getting from this:-

```
1495596971.6034188::automotive auto ebc greenstuff 6000 series supreme truck 
and suv brake pads dp61603 https:\/\/t.co\/jpylzjyd5o cars\u2026 
https:\/\/t.co\/gfsbz6pkj7""display_text_range:[0140]source:""\u003ca 
href=\""https:\/\/dlvrit.com\/\"" 
rel=\""nofollow\""\u003edlvr.it\u003c\/a\u003e"""
"1495596972.330948::new free stock photo of city cars road 
https:\/\/t.co\/qbkgvkfgpp""display_text_range:[0"
"1495596972.775966::ebay: 1974 volkswagen beetle - classic 1952 custom 
 conversion extremely rare 1974 vw beetle\u2026\u2026 
 https:\/\/t.co\/wdsnf2pmo7""display_text_range:[0140]source:""\u003ca 
 href=\""https:\/\/dlvrit.com\/\"" 
rel=\""nofollow\""\u003edlvr.it\u003c\/a\u003e"""
```

I want date and time in standard format rather than "1495596971.6034188".
Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: You also have the option of using the tweet's creation date. It is embedded in the JSON as `"created_at":"Wed Aug 27 13:08:45 +0000 2008"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is basic example converting unix timestamp to readable date:

```
import datetime
print(
    datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int("1495596971")
    ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
)
>>2017-05-24 03:36:11
```

You need to split() ""1495596971.6034188" by "." and use the first index[0]